# Como usar um cron job do Rails para executar um programa em Java?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, cron

É possível usar um cron job no Rails para executar um comando que executa uma classe em Java? Se sim como?

Comment: você falar em executar um .jar já compilado em java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar a gem chamada [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) elá irá manter seu crontab em código ruby, a ideia é escrever todas as regras e junto com o deploy fazer a atualização da crontab.

1º No seu GemFile insira

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

2º Crie o arquivo *schedule.rb*

```
wheneverize .
```

3º No arquivo schedule.rb

```
#aqui você pode definir a frequência que o código vai ser executado, ler readme do github
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  command "java {chamada do programa java}"
end
```

4º No servidor executar o comando para atualizar a tabela crontab, caso esteja utilizando o capristano, colocar no seu fluxo de deploy

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

O Rails não tem cron job, isso é tarefa do sistema operacional. E sim, vc pode usar o cron para chamar um programa em java, dede que ele seja "chamável" por linha de comando.